# android - EditText with onFocusChangeListener in ListView bug

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` for which I made a custom adapter. Some items in the list have an `EditText`for which I set `onFocusChangeListener` to store the data typed in it.

The problem is:
Focusing an `EditText` from the `ListView`, after the soft keyboard is displayed, the focus on that `EditText` is lost. It can be focused by selecting it again. How do I avoid this?

The `getView()` method in the custom adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch(type)
            {
                case NORMAL:

                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_edit_content, parent, false);
                    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowName);
                    holder.input = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.input);
                    break;
                case SPECIAL:/* some code */
                    break;
            }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        switch(type)
        {
        case NORMAL:
            holder.title.setText(columnNames.get(position));
            holder.input.setText(data.get(position));
            holder.input.setId(position);
            holder.input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    final int pos = v.getId();
                    EditText txt = (EditText) v;
                        data.set(pos, txt.getText().toString());
                }
            });
            break;
        case SPECIAL: /* some other code */ 
            break;
        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

The `list_item_edit_content.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#0000ff" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not that I am sure it will fix your problem, but your onFocusChange event will likely want to take hasFocus into account. Else it will perform the event when you gain focus, or when you lose focus (unless that is what you want).

Comment: Set isFocusable="false" on parent elements in your xml

Comment: @GregEnnis I think you meant android:focusable="false", in which case it doesn't work. I also removed the <requestFocus /> from xml and it still not working.

Comment: yeah I only put it in a comment cause I didnt know if it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that the problem lies in activity recreation when the keyboard is shown. Prevent this by adding in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: I think that the problem lies there as well, but  don't have the knowledge yet to figure out how to make it work as intended (I'm new to java and android)

Comment: I already tried it when I was deciding my layout design and adjustPan will place last few items from the list behind the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance yet to copy and run this code, but I can tell you right off the bat that I have found not to trust the "view.getId()" method when it comes to ListViews and Adapters.

Even programmatically retrieving a child from a ListView and then running child.getId() has never been reliable.

I have had many problems with it not returning the ID of "what we think is the view" because the adapter re-uses the views which complicates things.

I would look into the methods: "hasFocus" and "requestFocus". Some other View or ViewGroup is obtaining focus. 
Try:

```
    Log.i("TAG", "View with focus = " + getCurrentFocus());
    Log.i("TAG", "View with focus = " + getCurrentFocus().getId());
```

Find out which view is gaining focus and then go from there.

They have proven very useful and backwards compatible for me.